# How to filter through 2 List<List<string> > colections to get matching BLOCKS, for the least Time

Tags: c#, regex, linq

Good day.
I'm new to c# programming.
My current project consist of 2 separate main folders, with multiple folders, with files..of which a number of lines differ in each file. For Folder-A, there's a total of about 4000 files, with an average of 2000 up to 10'000 lines/file...the approximate same on Folder-B.

I've put these files and lines into lists..and did some stuff with the "text" lines in some files.

Now, I need to match them up to see which sections of which files for folder A, match sections of files for folder B.

Only one match block is allowed per folder, tho there might be many different blocks, if more than one match of the block is found, the block size needs to be  increased, up to the maximum size of the line count of the file.

My method does work, but, because I'm not into everyday programming,my logic might not be the fastest.

Here is what i have done:

```
  public static bool ContainsAllItems(List<string> a, List<string> b)
        {
            return !b.Except(a).Any();
        }


    int fileCountA = 0;
    int lineCountA = 0;
    int fileCountB = 0;
    int lineCountB = 0;
    int filenrB = 0;
    int linenrB = 0;
    bool Found1 = false;
    bool Found2 = false;
    bool FoundReset =false;
    int ChecklinestartA = 0;
    int ChecklinestartB = 0;
    int Checkline = 3;
    List<string> TempListA = new List<string>();
    List<string> TempListB = new List<string>();
    List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>> PlaceFound = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>>();

    TempListA.Clear();
    TempListB.Clear();

    foreach (List<string> testlistA in FolderA)
    {
        fileCountA++;
        lineCountA = 0;
        ChecklinestartA = 0;
        do  //Do While File A
        {
            lineCountA++;
            TempListA.Clear();
            for (int i = ChecklinestartA; i <= ChecklinestartA + Checkline; i++)
            {
                TempListA.Add(testlistA[i]);

            }

            foreach (List<string> testlistB in FolderB)
            {
                fileCountB++;
                lineCountB = 0;

                ChecklinestartB = 0;
                do//Do While File B
                {
                    lineCountB++;
                    TempListB.Clear();
                    if (!Found1)
                    {
                        for (int i = ChecklinestartB; i <= ChecklinestartB + Checkline; i++)
                        {

                            if (testlistB[i] != null)

                            {

                                TempListB.Add(testlistB[i]);

                            }


                        }
                        Found1 = ContainsAllItems(TempListA, TempListB);
                        filenrB = fileCountB;
                        linenrB = lineCountB;
                    }
                    else if ((Found1)&&(!Found2))
                    {
                        for (int i = ChecklinestartB; i <= ChecklinestartB + Checkline; i++)
                        {

                            if (testlistB[i] != null)

                            {

                                TempListB.Add(testlistB[i]);

                            }


                        }
                        Found2 = ContainsAllItems(TempListA, TempListB);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        break;
                    }


                        ChecklinestartB++;
                }
                while ((ChecklinestartB + Checkline) <= TempListB.Count);//Do While File B
                if ((Found1) && (Found2))
                {
                    Found1 = false;
                    Found2 = false;
                    filenrB = 0;
                    linenrB = 0;
                    FoundReset = true;

                    break;
                }

            }
            if ((!FoundReset) && (Found1))
            {
                //only one match, reset checkline, increase startingpoint on File A list A, reset found1, add the match to the list of place found, with file a, file nr, line nr, and file B, file nr, line nr as references.
                Found1 = false;

                KeyValuePair<int, int> FileAPosition = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(fileCountA, lineCountA);
                KeyValuePair<int, int> FileBPosition = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(filenrB, linenrB);
                KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>> ThisPosition = new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>(FileAPosition, FileAPosition);
                PlaceFound.Add(ThisPosition);
                ChecklinestartA = ChecklinestartA + Checkline;
            }
            else if (FoundReset)

            {
                //double found, increase amount of lines to be checked, found1 and 2 already resetted
                FoundReset = false;
                Checkline=Checkline+2;
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing found increase startingpoint on file A, up to where do>>while finish
                ChecklinestartA++;



            }
```

I need a better, or Quicker way, of sorting thru the logic and blocks.

Basically..it starts with Folder A, first file of the list, then make a "block" of the first 3 lines of the file.

It goes to folder B, first file, create the same block size.
Compares them..if it matches, mark as found1, then move folder B file1 block on by one or a few lines, continue with the matching process, until done with the first file, goes to next one.

Continues the matching cycle,if it goes thru all files in folder B without out another match, the matched position gets recorded.If a 2nd match is found, match position gets reset, file A Block size gets increased or moved along.

Once the block size matches the file size, and they are still multiple matched, this should be marked and counted as a "special occurrence"

In the event that no match of the block gets found, the block location in folder A file 1 gets moved along.This all gets repeated until it is through all line of all files in Folder A.

Hope it all makes sense.As I'm doing these in my spare time, and it was a complicated bit of logic 
:)
regards

Comment: done, tho, my native language is not English, thus, i might have grammatical errors etc. Please bear with the in-discrepancies.

Comment: use JOIN.  See msdn exmaples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad. Questions about how to improve programs that work may be a better fit on codereview.stackexchange.com, but first please read their help pages on what is on-topic and on how to write a good question there.

Comment: It look like it could be polish to a code review to me.

Comment: 1rst check if it's a [MCVE] The code you show must be self containt. Here the input are easy to come up with but the expected output can be precise.. [Code review migration check list](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1689#1689)

Comment: Hi @Ludwig, this question seems pretty broad, open-ended for Stack Overflow. if you have code that is working, but you need to make it more performant, consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), instead. However, don't just copy and paste... be sure to take their tour and make sure your question fits their rules!